# Realm change event & synchronization context

Tags: c#, realm

I'd like to get notifications when Realm is changed on the server.
The https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#notifications says that synchronization context must be installed (i.e. for Android). I've set up *Nito.AsyncEx* (see code below), but it isn't working: `realm.RealmChanged` is not triggered when Realm is changed.

### Code

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            AsyncContext.Run(async () => await Loop());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task Loop()
        {
            // get user info & realm URL

            var syncConfiguration = new FullSyncConfiguration(realmUrl, user);

            Console.WriteLine(SynchronizationContext.Current);

            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(syncConfiguration);

            realm.RealmChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Realm has changed");
            };    
        }
```

GitHub issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1841

Comment: What does "it isn't working" mean? What behavior do you see and what behavior do you expect?

Comment: @StephenCleary I've updated the question. I expect RealmChanged event to be triggered when Realm is changed, but it is not triggered.